# Set after value for DIV dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a div container that will layout each item evenly for the full width of the screen.

I would like to adjust the BACK div behind the selected input dynamically.
I know in theory how to do it: do a transform: translate to #after of the BACK div. But I have no idea how to calculate the correct px value, depending on what input tag has been selected.

The codepen to view this is available here: https://codepen.io/depechie/pen/oNZagLa

The desired end result visually should be like following picture. So the BACK div ( the blue outline ) should be placed behind the selected input.

[image]

```js
function openLink(link) {
  alert(link);
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400");
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bottombarcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: #66ccff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bottombarcontainer .bottombar {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  bottom: 0;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.bottombarcontainer .bottombar #back {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  height: 45px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}


/* .bottombarcontainer .bottombar #back::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #66ccff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  transform: translate(5px, 0);
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
} */

.bottombarcontainer .bottombar input[type="radio"]:checked+.round {
  transform: translate(0, -7px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: white;
}

.bottombarcontainer .bottombar input[type="radio"]:checked+.round svg {
  color: #66ccff;
}

.bottombarcontainer .bottombar input {
  display: none;
}

.bottombarcontainer .bottombar .round {
  position: relative;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, 5px);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  will-change: transform;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.bottombarcontainer .bottombar .round svg {
  height: 100%;
  color: #aaa;
  line-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottombarcontainer">
  <div class="bottombar">
    <input type="radio" name="tap" id="t0" checked="checked">
    <label class="round" for="t0">
    <span class="icon">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M13,9H11V7H13M13,17H11V11H13M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z" />
        </svg>
    </span>
      </label>
    <input type="radio" name="tap" id="t1" onchange="openLink('docs')">
    <label class="round" for="t1">
    <span class="icon">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-list">
        <line x1="8" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6"></line>
        <line x1="8" y1="12" x2="21" y2="12"></line>
        <line x1="8" y1="18" x2="21" y2="18"></line>
        <line x1="3" y1="6" x2="3" y2="6"></line>
        <line x1="3" y1="12" x2="3" y2="12"></line>
        <line x1="3" y1="18" x2="3" y2="18"></line>
      </svg>
    </span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="tap" id="t2">
    <label class="round" for="t2">
    <span class="icon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M12.74,5.47C15.1,6.5 16.35,9.03 15.92,11.46C17.19,12.56 18,14.19 18,16V16.17C18.31,16.06 18.65,16 19,16A3,3 0 0,1 22,19A3,3 0 0,1 19,22H6A4,4 0 0,1 2,18A4,4 0 0,1 6,14H6.27C5,12.45 4.6,10.24 5.5,8.26C6.72,5.5 9.97,4.24 12.74,5.47M11.93,7.3C10.16,6.5 8.09,7.31 7.31,9.07C6.85,10.09 6.93,11.22 7.41,12.13C8.5,10.83 10.16,10 12,10C12.7,10 13.38,10.12 14,10.34C13.94,9.06 13.18,7.86 11.93,7.3M13.55,3.64C13,3.4 12.45,3.23 11.88,3.12L14.37,1.82L15.27,4.71C14.76,4.29 14.19,3.93 13.55,3.64M6.09,4.44C5.6,4.79 5.17,5.19 4.8,5.63L4.91,2.82L7.87,3.5C7.25,3.71 6.65,4.03 6.09,4.44M18,9.71C17.91,9.12 17.78,8.55 17.59,8L19.97,9.5L17.92,11.73C18.03,11.08 18.05,10.4 18,9.71M3.04,11.3C3.11,11.9 3.24,12.47 3.43,13L1.06,11.5L3.1,9.28C3,9.93 2.97,10.61 3.04,11.3M19,18H16V16A4,4 0 0,0 12,12A4,4 0 0,0 8,16H6A2,2 0 0,0 4,18A2,2 0 0,0 6,20H19A1,1 0 0,0 20,19A1,1 0 0,0 19,18Z" />
</svg>
    </span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="tap" id="t3">
    <label class="round" for="t3">
    <span class="icon">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-list">
        <line x1="8" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6"></line>
        <line x1="8" y1="12" x2="21" y2="12"></line>
        <line x1="8" y1="18" x2="21" y2="18"></line>
        <line x1="3" y1="6" x2="3" y2="6"></line>
        <line x1="3" y1="12" x2="3" y2="12"></line>
        <line x1="3" y1="18" x2="3" y2="18"></line>
      </svg>
    </span>
    </label>
    <div class="div" id="back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. What is the expected output?

Comment: thx @mplungjan did not know that was possible, cool!! And yes same result als codepen.

Comment: What do you need it to do exactly?

Comment: My sample is based on this: https://codepen.io/simoberny/pen/bzLRYe so each time you select one off the bottom inputs, the back div should be shown and placed centerer behind the input. But instead of the other codepen with dynamic calculation instead of fixed pixels.

Comment: I still do not get what you want. The codepen/snippet seems to change its background nicely. What are you trying to improve?

Comment: The other codepen will show a BLUE outline behind the selected input... it's that same effect I'm looking for.

Comment: Perhaps show an image of your expected output. It is not useful for us to go externally, in case the codepen is changed or disappear

Comment: Good call! Will add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a border on the selected element ?

```
 .bottombarcontainer .bottombar input[type="radio"]:checked + .round {
  transform: translate(0, -7px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: white;
  border:8px solid #66ccff ;
}
```

Comment: Woow so easy! ( yeah I'm not a web dev so I did not know this was possible )

Comment: Hmm there seems to be something wrong with the animations though... when adding the border, the items shift a few pixels to the left and right. Any idea?

Comment: You can add a transparent border the same weight to the default element : 
border:8px solid transparent ;

Comment: I guess that is added to the .bottombarcontainer .bottombar .round? Because border:8px; there has not much effect in the codepen?

Comment: Yep on .bottombarcontainer .bottombar .round{} ! The few pixel shift come from the difference between a 0px border (origin) to a 8px border (result).

Comment: Yeah got that... but if you look at the new pen ( https://codepen.io/depechie/pen/oNZagLa ) you'll notice the shift is still there. ( not sure what I'm doing wrong though )

Comment: Adding "8px solid transparent;" and not only "8px" works like a charm, you need to specify the kind of border you want an force the color to be transparent.